# Increasing font size in menu and files drop downs in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I know I have worked out how to do this before but can't remember how. I am working in RStudio through two monitors attached through a hub to a (closed) laptop. I increased the font size of the source, console, environment, and help panes but the font size of the tab names above the bottom right and top left panels remain very small (see image)

[image]

I have tried going into the computer's settings via Settings -> Ease of Access -> Display and increased the slider and raised 'Make everything bigger from 100% to 125% (see image), all to no avail

[image]

Can anyone who has had and solved this problem help me out?

Answer (score 0):

[Tools > Global Options > Appearance > Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq4PS.png)

Click the link above for a screenshot.

If you go to Tools > Global Options > Appearance > Zoom,

You will be able to increase size of everything by adjusting the zoom.

If you are on rstudio-server, ctrl + will do the same thing.